# Excel: Export to PDF not updating

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm trying to get Excel to export my table as a PDF file. Problem is, it always exports the PDF with the same data. It doesn't matter if I add more entries or remove them.

Here is the code I have managed to put together with my beginners VBA skills:

```
Sub export_pdf()

Dim area As String
area = Range("B3:H1048576").End(xlUp).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).Address

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$3:$3"
End With

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "" & area

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterHeader = "Käyttöpäiväkirja"
    .CenterFooter = "Sivu &P / &N"
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.590551181102362)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 100
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
End With


ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat pbFixedFormatPDF, "käyttöpäiväkirja.pdf"

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out the problem had nothing to do with Excel. Windows 8.1 PDF reader doesn't entirely close after you press 'X', which apparently prevents making changes to the file. It works fine if I close the reader from task manager.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it looks fine except for:

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat pbFixedFormatPDF, "käyttöpäiväkirja.pdf"
```

You actually need to supply the full path name for your file along with the .pdf extension.

I reckon it'd be something like `Drive:\Folder\SubFolder....\Filename.pdf`. You can always use Windows `Special Folder` using `FileSystemObject` class to a get user-independent paths if you're going to share it with other users.

I would highly suggest you let Excel determine the last row of data instead of arbitrarily setting an a extreme high long in your `H` column. I think doing it like this would make your code run faster in the run-time:

```
Dim lastrow As Long
With ActiveSheet
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
End With
area = Range("B3:H" & lastrow).End(xlUp).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).Address
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. Thanks for your help!